# Delete Files in Folder B that have the same Prefix as files in Folder A Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to do the following.  If I have folder A:

```
File1.ext
File2.ext
File3.ext
```

I want to delete anything in folder B that begins with the same prefix.  So if I have this in folder B:

```
File1-1.ext
File2-3.ext
```

I want them to be deleted.

I've been trying to use this:

```
For %%F In ("C:\FolderA\*.*") Do If Exist "C:\FolderB\%%~nF" Del "C:\FolderB\%%~nF"
```

But it won't work for me if there is a "-1" for instance on the file in folder B.  I tried using an asterisk but that did not work.  I'm totally brand new to this, and your help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The asterisk will most definitely work.  And there is no need to check if the file exists before deleting the file.  Just attempt to delete the file. Update your question with the code you tried to use with the asterisk.

Comment: Have you tried `@For %%A In ("C:\FolderA\*.ext") Do @Del /Q "C:\FolderB\%%~nA*.ext" 2>Nul`?

Comment: A slight modification to my previous comment, _(as the question technically states **anything in Folder B that begins with the same prefix**)_: `@For %%A In ("C:\FolderA\*.ext") Do @Del /Q "C:\FolderB\%%~nA*" 2>Nul`; _change `.ext` as required_.

Comment: Thanks Compo, this seems to be working for me.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer please checking the tick symbol next to my answer. You can also upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to take the filename **ONLY** from files in `FolderA` and search if exist in `FolderB`. So, you need to try something like this:

```bat
for %%I IN ("C:\FolderA\*.*") do del /q "C:\FolderB\%%~nI*"
```

where `%%~nI` means filename only of files found in `FolderA`.

Hope this helps!